# Rails 3 parent and child association scopes optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a parent has many children association in my project. I'm trying to get a list of children that have certain flags set from the parent when I render it.

For example this:

```
# some_controller
@thread = Thread.includes(:posts)
render :json => @thread.posts.as_json
```

will return something like

```
[
  { 
    "id" => 1, 
    "posts" => [
      { "id" => 1, "flagged" => true },
      { "id" => 2, "flagged" => false }
    ] 
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get the output to be like this

```
[
  { 
    "id" => 1, 
    "posts" => [
      { "id" => 2, "flagged" => false }
    ] 
  }
]
```

i.e.: only posts that are not flagged should be rendered.

I've overridden the `as_json` method in my model in order to do this as such:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  ...
  { 
    :id => self.id,
    :posts => self.posts
  }
  ...
end
```

I realize that I can define a scope in the Posts model and use `:posts => self.posts.not_flagged`, but this causes an extra database query for every thread in my database (makes everything slow).

Aside from a `default_scope` on the Posts model how else could I solve this extra query problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a bit after I posted.

I can add a scope in my Parent model to do this:

```
# Thread.rb
...
has_many :unflagged_posts, :class_name => "Post", :conditions => { :flagged => false }
...
```

And in my controller:

```
# some_controller
@threads = Thread.includes(:unflagged_posts)
```

This way ActiveRecord eager loads the posts with the flagged condition, rather than doing an extra query for each post!